# PHP: Check if a website is online

Tags: php, curl, web

I have a curl based function in php to check if a website is online that works fine however i have noticed that it only works for http links and not https links.

Does anyone know how this function can be updated to support https links also.

```
function isDomainAvailible($domain){
    // Check, if a valid url is provided
    if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize curl
    $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    // Get answer
    $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

    curl_close($curlInit);

    if ($response){ 
        return true;
    } else { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: alternatively you can try this for domain checking http://www.phpwhois.org/

Comment: https://github.com/HelgeSverre/Domain-Availability

Comment: Thanks for the links, i didn't want availability however but rather current online/offline status for the website. My function works fine but only for http and not https. I have a feeling there needs to be some extra curl added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your function and it u need https support then . you can download this file [cacert.pem](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and add the path in your function like:

```
function isDomainAvailible($domain){
// Check, if a valid url is provided
if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    return false;
}

// Initialize curl
$curlInit = curl_init($domain);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP);
curl_setopt ($curlInit, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
// Get answer
$response = curl_exec($curlInit);

curl_close($curlInit);

   if ($response){ 
    return 1;
   } else { 
    return 0;
   }
}
$domain = 'https://www.facebook.com';
$avi = isDomainAvailible($domain);
echo $avi;
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, 2 quick questions. 1) Is there a page with more info on the certificates thing (pem) and 2) I know it's valid but why do you use 1 and 0 rather than true and false booleans in your code is there any specific reason?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/241046/what-is-the-cacert-pem-and-for-what-to-use-that

Comment: You are welcome . No specific reason for 1 and 0 . just put for testing :)

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in curl function

```
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say, "i have noticed that it only works for http links and not https links", what exactly do you mean? cURL works the same either way, you just pass it a url with the https protocol instead of http. The problem might be something else. Does this sound like what you're having trouble with? [How to send HTTPS posts using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154172/how-to-send-https-posts-using-php)

Comment: I mean if you pass a https link it returns as false for some reason. I have just accepted an answer that uses certificates which fixes this issue.

Comment: Ah i see you add the extra item and it works. I just upvoted your answer.